# how train AdaBoost M1 weak estimators?

Tags: multi-class, multilabel, adaboost

I'm trying to implement AdaBoost.M1 as explained in *Boosting: Foundations and Algorithms* by Robert E. Schapire and Y. Freund. The problem is that I don't understand at each iteration *t* the estimator for which label should be trained. Here is the pseudocode of the algorithm from the book:

[image: AdaBoost.M1]

Answer (score 0):

AdaBoost is a technique to ensemble weak learners; the actual learner used can be anything that supports sample weights (possibly by just resampling according to those weights).  The most common learner for this is a decision tree, usually very shallow: very often only depth 1, a "decision stump."

Comment: Each `decision stump` can predict only a single label, right? If so, which label I should try to, let's say teach, a weak learner on each iteration?